# Flask-SQLAlchemy relationship many to many with Oracle database

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I declare oracle schema when create db instance:

```
oracle_schema = 'C##SHOP_USER'
oracle_db_metadata = schema.MetaData(schema=oracle_schema)
db = SQLAlchemy(metadata=oracle_db_metadata)

def create_app(config_class=Config):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(config_class)

    db.init_app(app)
```

And declare models with relationship:

```
class ShopProductLike(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "shop_product_like"

    shop_user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey(f'{oracle_schema}.shop_user.id'), primary_key=True)
    shop_product_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey(f'{oracle_schema}.shop_product.id'), primary_key=True)

class ShopProductCategory(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "shop_product_category"

    shop_product_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey(f'{oracle_schema}.shop_product.id'), primary_key=True)
    category_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey(f'{oracle_schema}.category.id'), primary_key=True)

class ShopProduct(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "shop_product"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.Sequence('shop_product_id_seq', start=1, increment=1), primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(128), nullable=False)
    author = db.Column(db.String(128), nullable=False)
    description = db.Column(db.String(1024), nullable=False, default='')
    date_of_creation = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow())
    image = db.Column(db.String(512))
    seller_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey(f'{oracle_schema}.shop_user.id'))

    categories = db.relationship('Category', secondary='shop_product_category', backref=db.backref('products'))
    likes = db.relationship('ShopUser', secondary='shop_product_like', backref=db.backref('likes_products'))
    seller = db.relationship('ShopUser')
```

But I get an error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: When initializing mapper mapped class ShopProduct->shop_product, expression 'shop_product_category' failed to locate a name ("name 'shop_product_category' is not defined"). If this is a class name, consider adding this relationship() to the <class 'app.database.ShopProduct'> class after both dependent classes have been defined.
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You're more likely to get a response if you detail the steps you took to try to solve your problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

In this method the `secondary` argument must point to a `Table` instance, not a model.

https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/flasky/issues/492#issuecomment-731370826

```
shop_product_like = db.Table('shop_product_like',
    db.Column('shop_user_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey(f'{oracle_schema}.shop_user.id'), primary_key=True),
    db.Column('shop_product_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey(f'{oracle_schema}.shop_product.id'), primary_key=True)
)

shop_product_category = db.Table('shop_product_category',
    db.Column('shop_product_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey(f'{oracle_schema}.shop_product.id'), primary_key=True),
    db.Column('category_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey(f'{oracle_schema}.category.id'), primary_key=True)
)

class ShopProduct(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "shop_product"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.Sequence('shop_product_id_seq', start=1, increment=1), primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(128), nullable=False)
    author = db.Column(db.String(128), nullable=False)
    description = db.Column(db.String(1024), nullable=False, default='')
    date_of_creation = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow())
    image = db.Column(db.String(512))
    seller_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey(f'{oracle_schema}.shop_user.id'))

    categories = db.relationship('Category', secondary=shop_product_category, backref=db.backref('products'))
    likes = db.relationship('ShopUser', secondary=shop_product_like, backref=db.backref('likes_products'))
    seller = db.relationship('ShopUser')
```